# Can't create a new version with Google Drive API 3

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to create a new version of a document using Google Drive API 3? I just found delete, get, list and update.

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct API for your specific purpose. You can actually do a [Revision list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)  search to get the version history of your file. Then you can perform a [Revision update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/update) with the information in the body parameters to perform such actions.

Moreover, if you want to create a brand new document starting from a version from your file, you can use the [Google Docs API][3] and add the parameter `revisionId": string,` in the  request body explain by the method in the API "Create".

Comment: It looks like both create a new file in the drive. What I'm looking for is to keep the file but add a new head revision.